# How to get user object by email filtering in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to get a specific user in Django via email filtering using default user model. I am doing the following in my views.py but it is not working:

```
def shareCode(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        email  = request.POST.get("mail")
        print(email)

        id =  int(request.POST.get('id'))
        user  = User.objects.get(email = email)
        obj = Code.objects.get(pk=id,user = user.id)
        res = {"shared":"fasle"}
        obj2 = Code(name=obj.name,code=obj.code,shared=True)
        obj2.save()
        res = {
            "shared":True
        }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(res))
```

**models.py**

```py
    class Code(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        code = models.TextField()
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        shared = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

but its getting be following error

```
Internal Server Error: /editor/share
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\stocksapp\main\views.py", line 138, in shareCode
    obj = Code.objects.get(id=id,user = user)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 390, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "D:\stocksapp\winenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'code'
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The error is *not* at that specific line, it is on a line with `obj = Code.objects.get(id=id,user = user)`.

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: are you sure `id` i` `3`, it looks like `id='code'`, so a `str`ing.

Comment: can you please share your model structure?

Comment: @ruddra please reffer to latest edit

Comment: I don't believe `id = 3`, can you share your exact view code? Have you really hard-coded `id = 3`?

Comment: Please refer to edit

Comment: print the value of `request.POST.get('id')` I believe it is "code"

Comment: Yes you are right.. The issue was from POST data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve an object from models using `exact` match.

e.g:

`user = User.objects.get(email__exact='usermail@example.com')`

This would generate SQL that looks like this:

`SELECT ... WHERE email = 'usermail@example.com';`

Comment: email is a case-insensitive data, `user = User.objects.get(email__iexact='usermail@example.com')` maybe better.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_user_email(user):
    """Return the email address of a user object"""
    return user.email

def send_email(to_email, subject, body):
    """Send an email to the given address with the given subject and body"""
    # Use a library like smtplib to send the email
    pass

def send_welcome_email(user):
    """Send a welcome email to the given user"""
    to_email = get_user_email(user)
    subject = "Welcome to our site!"
    body = "Thank you for signing up. We're excited to have you on board."
    send_email(to_email, subject, body)
```

Comment: Hi Yogeshwar Sahu, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Thanks